# android minimum hardware specs for dev machine - can i code using a notebook?

Tags: android, vim, requirements

So far I have been developing directly on my galaxy nexus and nexus 7 using the amazing AID app.

However, as the N7 can't provide logs due to it being jelly bean, i feel the need to get a mini notebook in order to utilise adb logcat.

My main worry is that something with only 1gb (2gb if i upgrade, which i will) and a 1.5-1.83GHz atom CPU won't be powerful enough.

I can possibly get around certain worries by not using emulators and testing directly on my two devices, so that will save me a great deal. Also I am tempted to just use vim and command line tools instead of eclipse which again might save me from a slow PC.

What do you guys think? Is the notebook way under powered? What if i just use vim and no emulators?

Side note, does anyone actually code in vim/command line?

Comment: My understanding is that you actually can enable log capture on Jellybrean devices by apps which request this permission, but have to jump through some hoops in the ADB shell to do so.  It's been discussed on the android google groups.

Comment: I need a machine to grab the logs though, hence the notebook.

Comment: No, actually you don't - it is supposedly still possible to collect and view them with an app on the device.  Though you do momentarily need one to run the adb command to authorize the app to do this.  Surely you have some sort of access to a computer running windows, linux, or osx?

Comment: @ChrisStratton - to read logs on a 4.1+ android device the device needs to be rooted (because devs left Facebook login details in the logs, and some accounts were hacked)

Comment: Yeah i do have another laptop, i could use it to sign an app once i guess. Its pretty bloated with stuff though hence why i want a totally stripped down machine just to develop on and won't run anything else on.

Comment: Jcw - this is what I've heard too, and am thinking of rooting but would lose all my data, plus looking around most guides need windows machine which i don't have access to. I could run a windows build on a vm, but then i still have to find a windows vm, then root it, lose my data etc, and then I'm still deving on a small keyboard.

Comment: @jcw at least when the READ_LOGS permission was first restricted out of privacy concerns early in the 4.x series, it was a "development" permission which could be enabled for a requesting app on unrooted devices with a pm command from the ADB shell (ie, not something uninformed users were supposed to do by accident).  Perhaps it has been further restricted since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> something with only 1gb (2gb if i upgrade, which i will) and a 1.5-1.83GHz atom CPU

will work just fine, as long as you're not planning to run a tablet emulator. I sometimes have to work at my Asus EEEPC with the same exact CPU and I've got no problems so far

Comment: Are you using eclipse or command line? Asus were one of the ones i was looking at, are they any good?

Comment: @RussWheeler Eclipse, running on Win XP. No complaints whatsoever

Comment: Great. Can you just give me your specs of the machine? What atom is it? What speed? 1gb or 2gb of ram?

Comment: @RussWheeler Here you go! [Specs](http://www.asus.com/Eee/Eee_PC/Eee_PC_1005PXD/#specifications) and [CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/49491), 2 Gb of RAM

Answer (score 1):

It is doable with 1gb RAM and using vim/commandline tools. However, eclipse provides a project wide perspective which is hard to duplicate in vim (vim power users may be as productive, if not more though). So in terms of memory 1, 2gb RAM will be fine. Testing on devices is always better than emulators.

One thing else though, a commandline build with multiple module dependency is non-trivial to setup and maintain. This is because Google has historically been modifying the build.xml file, breaking existing build scripts fairly regularly. So if you are well versed with build script internals and prepared to work on them you should be ok.

Debugging Android apps without Eclipse based breakpoint debugging support may be a significant issue too. Some bugs are caught in a lot lesser time with this. So plan accordingly if you don't want to use Eclipse.

Eclipse also provides very good JUnit/Robotium support for writing test cases, You won't get this with vim.

As I wrote down these points I think running Eclipse in 2gb notebook should be possible (just don't run other apps with doing development) and thus is recommended.

I have extensively used vim just not for Android development. You can also install vim plugin for eclipse if you prefer that.

Comment: My main idea to use vim was for speed of machine as opposed to development speed, but also to get better with vim at the same time.

I acknowledge that eclipse has lots of useful features and if i could get away with using it i probably would.

Answer (score 1):

Modern notebook hardware certainly is capable for software development; in fact, many (hobbyists as well as professionals) use a notebook as their main development platform.

However, with a mini / ultra-small form factor, you'll pay more for a less capable machine. Unless you need extreme mobility, I would suggest a standard notebook, with a little extra money spent on RAM (8+ GB) and an SSD. (Then, neither big IDEs nor emulation is out of scope.) If money is an issue, you can still get clunky-looking, but fairly powerful 15" or 17" laptops.

Comment: Yeah money is the key here. I've seen cheap notebooks on eBay for about £150. I'm still a hobbyist, so don't want to blow hundreds on something just yet.

Answer (score 0):

i think you Configuration is good enought to run Eclipse , Myself i had to Remove some Composant on my PC beacause we have 1 PC for Work/Internet/Eclipse and 1 PC for Gaming Etc ... , iam using Galaxy S2 and dont use Emulator many times , Yes i have some Slow Down some Time , but try Eclipse with the Minimal Configuration and No Emulators but Upgrade to 2 GB i have myself 2 GB Here and DUal Core E5200

Comment: i was blocked from answering post , i dont know if this is from the automatic filter beacause i answered few posts on the same time /OffTopic , No Problems .

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that's under powered. For a windows PC I'd want 4gb of ram, not sure about Linux but atoms are dog slow either way.

I'm sure it'll work but it won't be fun, I'd be most worried about disk speed as that's what drives me nuts most.

I'd also take advantage of the ide and all its nice features too

Comment: Well i wouldn't be using windows, I'd stick a version of Linux on, probably Ubuntu.